# How to calculate this indefinite integration？

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have following integration:

$$
\int {\frac{dx} {x + {\sqrt{ 1- x^{2} }}} }
$$

I'm trying to calculate it by letting `x=cos(t) , dx=-sin(t)dt` , and I got a very long result which is incorrect.

However, the correct answer is:

$$
{\frac {1} {2}} ( arcsin(x) + ln|x+{\sqrt{1-x^2}}| ) + C
$$

So, how can I calculate it?

Comment: Please edit your post to include your attempt. This can help us to help you. [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).